# Unable to delete Snapin - referenced by Pre-chat Form Quick Action that when clicked is URL not found

Tags: global-actions, snap-ins, embedded-services

My org has two snapins:

- `Snapins_Case_PrechatQuickAction_08hxxx`
- `Snapins_Contact_PrechatQuickAction_08hxxx`

When I try and delete these, I get an error saying they are used elsewhere in a `Pre-chat Form Quick Action`

[image]

Clicking that link redirects me to Classic and then I get a URL not found error

[image]

How do I delete these global action snapins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced `Pre-chat Form Quick Action` has a URL of:

```
/lightning/r/EmbeddedServiceQuickAction/09zXXXXXXXXXXXX/view
```

and when Lightning Setup prompts you to view it in Classic, the redirected URL is:

```
/09zXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

`09z` is `EmbeddedServiceQuickAction`

but Classic doesn't allow you to see Embedded Services in Classic Setup❗

So, basically, the dependency enforcement used by Setup delete assumes that you could see `EmbeddedServices` in Classic - perhaps due to the evolution from Live Agent.

**Solution**

In Lightning,

- go to `Setup | Embedded Services Deployments`,
- delete the deployment(s) at issue (if you no longer need them) or edit the deployments (if you want to remove chat buttons from specific objects).
- This will allow you to then delete the Global Action snapins from either Classic or Lightning